# Issues installing Sails on Ubuntu && node v.4

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, sails.io.js

I was wondering if anyone else has had problems installing sails in ubuntú vps with node v.4.

Thanks,
Marcos

> root@marcoscorreia:/# sudo npm install sails
>   |
>   sails@0.11.0 preinstall /node_modules/sails
>   node ./lib/preinstall_npmcheck.js
>
> Sails.js Installation: Checking npm-version successful
>   npm WARN deprecated grunt-lib-contrib@0.7.1: DEPRECATED. See readme: 
>   https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-lib-contrib
>
> utf-8-validate@1.1.0 install /node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-hook-
>   sockets/node_mod/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modu     > les/utf-8-validate
>   node-gyp rebuild